why is a tab being inserted into console when printing a tibble and how to fix
I often copy/paste a tibble from the RStudio console into the R script that I'm working on, and when I do that, 2 spaces are inserted before the first row, which I find annoying. Is this avoidable? I don't see this behavior if I paste into Notepadd++, which makes me think this is specific to pasting into RStudio.

I don't know where to even start to find the solution for this.
